# Prove the following (probability):

Tags: probability

$$|P(AB)-P(AC)|\leq P(B∆C)$$ $$P(A ∆ B)\leq P(A∆C)+P(C∆B)$$ Do there exist A,B,C elements of F(sigma algebra)  so that: $P(A∆B)+P(B∆C)< 2/3 $ Tried. No avail.  The triangle is the simmetric difference.

Comment: Might be useful to explain what "∆" means...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if $A=B=C=F$? Then all of the set symmetric probabilities are $0$, and $|P(AB) - P(AC)| = 0$ as well.

Comment: Thats a specific situation, not general.